# In spring Lombok's annotations are not effective（maybe this is the bug）

Tags: java, spring, lombok

Mycode:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class CallResult<T> implements Serializable {

    private int code;

    private String message;

    private T result;
    

    public static <T>CallResult<T> success() {
        return new CallResult<T>(200, "default success", null);
    }
}
```

My dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>
```

JDK:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vMrT.png)

Error Info:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJccA.png)

I learned that using annotations in Lombok can reduce some redundant code, such as constructors, get and set methods, etc

But after I added the annotation, it prompted me to add a constructor.

I thought it was a compatibility issue with the versions of jdk11 and lombok 1.18.20, but it is compatible.

Then I also opened the settings --> Enable annotation processing

I don't know how to solve this problem, please help me

Comment: remove  <version>1.18.24</version> line from dependency and try mvn clean install. May be a version issue.

Comment: thank you bro. Importing dependencies in the XML file did not make it effective. I downloaded the Lombok plugin from Idea and restarted it ，then it works.

Comment: Did you try using the Builder to create your object instead of the constructor?

Comment: Current version is 1.18.30 (and ~tomorrow, 1.18.32, a release is imminent), and you need to install lombok into eclipse as per instructions, which OP appears to have now done. Commenting here for any future readers that find this question.

Comment: @PranjalGore it's already works, thank you